# Can't cat a file or make a directory: contradictory output?

Tags: command-line, files, directory, cat

I am getting output from a terminal in Ubuntu 12 that I don't understand.

```
$cat sublime
no such file or directory

$mkdir sublime
cannot create directory 'sublime': File exists
```

How can both of these be true? I am trying to install sublime text with [these](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/getting_started/install.html) instructions but having trouble making a symbolic link because /usr/bin/sublime does not exist.

Comment: What is the output of `ls -ld sublime`?

Comment: may be `sublime` file contain `no such file or directory` unix prank :P, So try `nl sublime` or check with `ls -thor`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A "file" can be a [couple of things](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_file_types). For example `man find` lists:

```
  -type c
          File is of type c:

          b      block (buffered) special
          c      character (unbuffered) special
          d      directory
          p      named pipe (FIFO)
          f      regular file
          l      symbolic link
          s      socket
          D      door (Solaris)
```

In your case that "file" might be a broken symlink or a regular file containing the text "no such file or directory".

You can use `ls -ld sublime` to find out. (The first character indicates the type of the file.)

Answer (score 2):

The sublime is probably a broken soft (symbolic) link to a removed file or directory.
You can use `ls -l` to see what it is linked to. The broken links are usually highlighted in red in the ls output.

Answer (score 2):

If the file is not present, you can't do `cat afile`. You need `cat > afile`. However, in your case, it seems that the file `sublime` is present with the text content: `no such file or directory`. If the file would not be there the exact message would have been:

```
$ cat afile
cat: afile: No such file or directory
```